# Skip existing node while loading csv

Tags: neo4j

i m new at neo4j and i d like to upload a csv file and create a set of nodes. However i have already some existing nodes that may exist on that csv file. Is there an option to load the csv, create the nodes based on each row and in case the node already exists skip that row?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) clause to avoid creating duplicate nodes and relationships.

However, you need to carefully read the documentation to understand how to use `MERGE`, as incorrect usage can cause the unintentional creation of nodes and relationships.

Answer (score 0):

[Merge](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) will give you what you want, however you must be careful *how you identify the record uniquely* to prevent creating duplicates

*I'll put the desired final form first as attention spans seem to be on the decline...*

```
// This one is safe assuming name is a true unique identifier of your Friends
// and that their favorite colors and foods may change over time
LOAD CSV FROM 'data/friends.csv' AS line
MERGE (f:Friend { name: line[0]})
set a.favorite_food = line[1]
set a.favorite_color = line[2]
```

The merge above will create or find the Friend node with that matching name and then, regardless of whether we are creating it or updating it, set the attributes on it.

If we were to instead provide all the attributes in the merge as such:

```
// This one is dangerous - all attributes must match in order
//                         to find the existing Friend node
LOAD CSV FROM 'data/friends.csv' AS line
MERGE (f:Friend { name: line[0], favorite_food: line[1], favorite_color: line[2]})
```

Then we would fail to find an existing friend everytime their favorite_food or favorite_color was updated in our data being (re)loaded.

Here's an example for anyone who's imagination hasn't fully filled in the blanks...

```
//Last month's file contained:
Bob Marley,Hemp Seeds,Green

//This month's file contained:
Bob Marley,Soylent Green,Rainbow
```